# SQL VBA query issue

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have used the following code which shows error in

```
.Open SQL, cn, , , adCmdText
```

when trying to debug. But the error shows that the syntax is wrong.

```
sql = "SELECT * from Employee Data Where Employee ID='" & txtUserName.Value _
        & "' AND Password = '" & txtPassword.Value _
        & "' order by Employee ID"
```

[image]

Comment: `Employee ID` should be `[Employee ID]` (due to the embedded space in the field name) and the same for `[Employee Data]`

Comment: This is why it is advised not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention. And not to use reserved words as names.

Comment: Might be worth using parameters too, sql injection could be an issue if you get into this bad habit

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 instances of Employee ID what should be delimited with [] and 1 instance of Employee Data that should be as well.

It should look something more like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * from [Employee Data] Where [Employee ID]='" _
    &  txtUserName.Value & "' AND Password = '" & txtPassword.Value _
    & "' order by [Employee ID]"
```

If it's early enough in your project, I would consider removing Spaces from the table and field names. The tend to be a problem in most languages

Common conventions are to either use PascalCaseInPlaceOfSpaces (more common in case-sensitive languages), camelCaseInPlaceOfSpaces or Underscores_In_Place_Of_Spaces